# suphp error on suPHP_UserGroup

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, suphp

i'm using ubuntu 15.04.

I have installed suphp (repo) with the guide from this url:
[Install suphp with apache on ubuntu](http://www.binarytides.com/install-suphp-ubuntu/)

After I define the virtual host like this example:

```
<VirtualHost 64.131.72.23:80>
ServerName some-site.com
ServerAlias www.some-site.com
DocumentRoot /home/mike/public_html
<IfModule mod_suphp.c>
    suPHP_UserGroup mike mike
</IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

I restarted apache service and got the error:

```
Invalid command 'suPHP_UserGroup', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration


:/etc/apache2/sites-available# systemctl status apache2.service -l
apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2016-01-20 00:36:26 CST; 41s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 18692 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/apache2 stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 18718 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jan 20 00:36:26 numi apache2[18718]: * The apache2 configtest failed.
Jan 20 00:36:26 numi apache2[18718]: Output of config test was:
Jan 20 00:36:26 numi apache2[18718]: AH00526: Syntax error on line 7 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/wpdev.co.il.c                           onf:
Jan 20 00:36:26 numi apache2[18718]: Invalid command 'suPHP_UserGroup', perhaps misspelled or defined by a modul                           e not included in the server configuration
Jan 20 00:36:26 numi apache2[18718]: Action 'configtest' failed.
Jan 20 00:36:26 numi apache2[18718]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Jan 20 00:36:26 numi systemd[1]: apache2.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jan 20 00:36:26 numi systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Apache2 web server.
Jan 20 00:36:26 numi systemd[1]: Unit apache2.service entered failed state.
Jan 20 00:36:26 numi systemd[1]: apache2.service failed.
```

**EDIT**

According to the first answer I have wrapped my suPHP_UserGroup in `<Directory>` and still the same error.
I'm not a big expert so no compiling for now, just to understand why a package used by a lot of people doesn't work for me.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.suphp.org/DocumentationView.html?file=apache/CONFIG

```
suPHP_UserGroup (expects user- and groupname)
```

Only supported when compiled with setid-mode "force" or "paranoid" * Specify the user- and groupname to run PHP-scripts with. This setting can only be used within a or context. Example: suPHP_UserGroup foouser bargroup

./configure --prefix=/usr --sysconfdir=/etc --with-apr=/usr/bin/apr-1-config --with-apxs=/usr/sbin/apxs --with-apache-user=apache --with-setid-mode=paranoid --with-php=/usr/bin/php-cgi --with-logfile=/var/log/httpd/suphp_log --enable-SUPHP_USE_USERGROUP=yes

more reference : [suPHP setting user/group to virtual host and using docroot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9263019/suphp-setting-user-group-to-virtual-host-and-using-docroot)

Comment: tryed to compile, getting this errors:   configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-php, --enable-SUPHP_USE_USERGROUP
configure: error: cannot find install-sh, install.sh, or shtool in config "."/config

Comment: This might help you

http://askubuntu.com/questions/27677/cannot-find-install-sh-install-sh-or-shtool-in-ac-aux

https://www.litespeedtech.com/support/wiki/doku.php?id=litespeed_wiki:php:lsapi